# ExtJS floating window focus lose detection

Tags: extjs, focus, window, blur, floating

I am wondering whether there is an efficient way to detect whether a floating window loses focus or not. I have a floating window for user's temporary inputs, what I want to do is automatically hiding this window if user forgot to hide it after input operation (e.g., clicks at elsewhere). I tried to use blur event on window's element, but nothing happened.
a working demo: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/7VBnB/2/)

thanks for any idea!

Answer (score 4):

This can be achieved adding blur event to ext window element, below is the sample code

```
    Ext.applyIf(me, {
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Done',
                listeners: {
                    click: {
                        fn: me.onDoneButtonClick,
                        scope: me
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        listeners: {
            el: {
                blur: {
                    fn: me.onWindowLoseFocus,
                    scope:me
                }
            }               
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Before you can detect if the window has been blurred or not, you'll need some action to blur a window in the first place. You mentioned that you'd like a window to blur if a user "clicks elsewhere"; you can accomplish this by adding a listener to your mainPanel:

```
var mainPanel = new Ext.Panel({ //define a main non-floating panel
    title: 'main',
    id: 'mainPanel',
    width: 400,
    height: 400,
    listeners: {
        afterrender: function(self) {
            self.body.on('click', function() {
                alert('clicked')
            });
        }
    }

});
```

Once the panel body has been clicked, you can blur floatWin so the events it is listening for actually fire.

Comment: thanks for your reply.. however, it only works for mainPanel's body. in my real app, there are several other containers, including some other floating ones, I think it's not a good idea to register 'click' event for each of them.