# Ext JS 4: Ext.Component focus and blur events

Tags: extjs4, focus, extjs4.2, blur

I have been working on this simple test code, and I can't seem to get the focus and blur events to work properly. What I'm imagining is the user moving their mouse over the window (fires focus event), and then the user moves their mouse out of the window (fires blur event). Unfortunately, this is not the case, and maybe I'm just misunderstanding [blur](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-event-blur) and [focus](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.window.Window-event-focus).

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
  height: 300,
  width: 300,
  title: 'blah',
  autoShow: true,
  listeners: {
    focus: function() {
      alert('focused!');
    },
    blur: function() {
      alert('blurred!');
    }
  }
});
```

[Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/49f)

Now, I did find [this Stack post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143777/extjs-floating-window-focus-lose-detection)... very interesting that you can put el inside of listeners like that. Unfortunately, it looks like when the page loads, the window gains focus and then loses it right away... same if I hover over it. So I'm confused. The API says you can use focus and blur just like every other listener (no mentioning of wrapping it in el), but this post says you need to wrap it in el?

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding focus and blur. As far as I know, mousing over something doesn't give it focus, so it wouldn't fire the focus event. An example of something receiving focus would be clicking inside a text field.

Comment: So I thought that was another possibility, but clicking the window/dragging it around still doesn't give it focus.

Comment: `div` doesn't have a focus event, and that is likely the underlying HTML element you are clicking on. Only certain HTML tags can be 'focused' on, though I couldn't tell you exactly which ones.

Comment: Huh.  Interesting.  So this seems like a pretty useless event then...

Comment: Also, calling `win.focus()` (where `win` is what I created above) doesn't fire the focus event either... that was what really boggled my mind, but I guess that's because focus doesn't fire any events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is JavaScript 101, and I still get it wrong.  Focus and blur are for when you click the element (gains view focus) and when you click out of the element (loses view focus), respectively.  The only strange thing is, why does `window.focus()` not actually fire the focus event?  It's most likely because it doesn't fire any events, but why is that?  You would think a method called focus would fire the focus event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the focus and blur events with form fields.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34126211)